# how do i sync/copy exacttarget production account content to our sandbox account?

Tags: marketing-cloud

To avoid having to recreate all the content in our production account in our sandbox account, is there a tool to just copy the content of interest automatically?

Comment: It seems to me they set it up all manually. Also you can only link one exacttarget account to an org, so if you do copy it down to a sandbox it wont work. Changes will need to be made on tje ExactTarget side.

Answer (score 1):

There currently is no tool to copy from one account to another.  This can be done via the API, but nothing exists that is specific to this type of functionality.